# Yosemite Security Defaults

Tags: macos, security

I've just made a fresh Yosemite install and noticed two strange security defaults

- Firewall is disabled
- User is created as an admin account

It is hard for me to imagine how a disabled firewall is a sane default, but I wonder if having my main user being an admin is OK.

Is the current privilege scaling built into OSX good enough so we no longer need a separate admin account?

Any good Apple reason for which the firewall should be disabled?

Comment: You are absolutly right these are 2 defaults.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this article for more information about the Firewall and how to enable it: https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18646?locale=en_US

It is fine if the main computer user is an admin. You will still need to enter your password to authorize changes to the computer, the only thing that is different from being a standard user (in this scenario) is that your username will be automatically entered. As an administrator, you also cannot delete important system files (built-in apps, operating system files, etc.).